# Nutch hadoop map reduce java heap space outOfMemory

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, nutch

I am running a Nutch 1.16, Hadoop 2.83, Solr 8.5.1 crawler setup that is running fine up to a few million indexed pages. Then I am running into Java Heap Space issues during the MapReduce job and I just cannot seem to find the correct way to up that heap space. I have tried:

1. Passing `-D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=24608 -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx24096m` when starting nutch crawl.
2. Editing NUTCH_HOME/bin/crawl commonOptions mapred.child.java.opts to `-Xmx16000m`
3. Setting HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml mapred.child.java.opts to `-Xmx160000m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`
4. Copying said mapred-site.xml into my nutch/conf folder

None of that seems to change anything. I run into the same Heap Space error at the same point in the crawling process. I have tried reducing the fetcher threads back to 12 from 25 and switching off parsing while fetching. Nothing changed and I am out of ideas. I have 64GB RAM so thats really not an issue. Please help ;)

EDIT: fixed filename to mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Passing `-D ...`

The heap space needs to be set also for the reduce task using "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb" and "mapreduce.reduce.java.opts". Note that the script bin/crawl was recently improved in this regard, see [NUTCH-2501](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2501) and the recent [bin/crawl script](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/9139d6ec7a98aea1af943755e9802066803b02b7/src/bin/crawl#L30).

> 3./4. Setting/copying hadoop-site.xml

Shouldn't this be set in "mapred-site.xml"?

Comment: Thanks trying with the added -D reduce setings right now. The hadoop-site.xml was a typo. I got confused with all the config files. Is there a top level setting to increase all java heaps for nutch/hadoop? Monitoring with visualVM shows all tasks stopping at 1000M and I want to give just everything more HeapSpace.

Comment: I think I found the nutch config in bin/nutch NUTCH_HEAPSIZE. Set everything to 4GB, thumbs are pressed. Will report back in a few hours ;-)

Comment: Setting NUTCH_HEAPSIZE as environment variable works only in local mode, not in a Hadoop cluster, see the comments in [bin/nutch](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/9139d6ec7a98aea1af943755e9802066803b02b7/src/bin/nutch#L37).

Comment: Thanks good to know. So far I only intend to run it locally and it is working fine so far. I am quite happy thanks again! Two iterations and 7 hours runtime. LinkDB, Parser, Generator and Indexer are all quite happy with more heap space.